# Javascript: refactor function outside of loop

Tags: javascript, jshint

So JSHint tells me I should not make functions within a loop.
I then usually make a function outside the loop.

But now I have a part where this is more difficult:

```
for (r=0;r<x;r++) {
    for (c=0;c<y;c++) {
        var arr = [c,r];
        setTimeout( (function(arr) { return function() { doSomething(arr); };})(arr), 50+c*550 + r*230 );
    }
}
```

how could i refactor this part to not get the JSHint warning?

Comment: I don't think an answer can be given without providing more context. Where is y defined? What is this snipped doing, and why are you executing settimout in a loop (which looks like a code smell in itself)?

Comment: x and y are just some integer variables. what is bad about setTimeouts in a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simple:

```
for (r=0;r<x;r++) {
    for (c=0;c<y;c++) {
        var arr = [c,r];
        setTimeout( proxy(arr), 50+c*550 + r*230 ); 
    }
}

function proxy(arr){
    return function(){
        doSomething(arr);
    };
}
```